# Problem regarding polynomial equation: $3bx^{a+4} = -24 x^6$

Tags: polynomials, exponentiation

How can we prove that:

- $3b$ equals to $-24$
- and that $a+4$ equals to $6$

in the following equation?

> $$
> 3bx^{a+4} = -24x^6
> $$

Can we not find any values of $b$ or $a$ that satisfy the above equation such that $3b$ does NOT equal to $-24$ and/or that $a+4$ does NOT equal to $6$?

Comment: Presumably, in the context of the problem, $b$ is an unknown _constant_, and $x$ is an indeterminate, which can take any value. So letting $x=1$, you get . . .

Comment: @quasi I see. Now it makes perfect sense! Can you turn that into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Brahadeesh's answer seems fine to me.

Comment: @quasi Not really. I understand your comment in an instant, but I can't make much of his/her answer. It seems like an overcomplicated solution to a simple question.

Comment: @Gnoliz where exactly is the difficulty?

Comment: @Brahadeesh I guess I'm lacking basic maths knowledge. Your answer is a statement that I have to memorise, whereas his answer is an explanation of why it is so.

Comment: @Gnoliz not an issue, it’s good to know that you found help on this site :)

Comment: @Brahadeesh Yeah it's a great site, especially when you try to relearn what you learnt in school as an adult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in my comment . . .

Presumably, in the context of the problem, $b$ is an unknown *constant*, and $x$ is an indeterminate, which can take any value.

So letting $x=1$, we get $3b=-24$, hence $b=-8$.

Replacing $3b$ by $-24$, the given identity reduces to $x^{a+4}=x^6$, and $x$ can still take any value.

So letting $x=2$, we get $2^{a+4}=2^6$, which implies $a+4=6$, hence $a=2$.

In this solution, we are not assuming $3bx^{a+2}$ is specified to be a polynomial.

But if the context of the problem allows that assumption, then as in Brahadeesh's answer, it's automatic that $a+4=6$, else the degrees won't match, and then we must have $3b=-24$, else the corresponding coefficients won't match.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \dots + a_n x^n$ and $q(x) = b_0 + b_1 x + \dots + b_m x^m$ be two polynomials. Then, $p = q$ if and only if $m = n$ and $a_i = b_i$ for each $0 \leq i \leq n$.

In other words, two polynomials are equal if and only if they have the same degree and the coefficient of each monomial is the same in both polynomials.

---

Here, the LHS is the polynomial $3b x^{a+4}$ and the RHS is the polynomial $-24x^6$. By the above statements, these polynomials are equal if and only if
$$a + 4 = 6 \quad \text{and} \quad 3b = -24.$$